# How to Calculate Smart LED Downlight Size & Quantity?

Tags: electrical, lighting

We want to use the new smart recessed LED downlights.  How do I calculate the location, size, brightness, number etc?  Is there an app for that?

We're building out a 24x14 family room.  Framing and heating is done.  Now working on the electrical.  Outlets are in.  Lights are next.

Comment: there are "apps" for that (eg. archicad), but they probably cost more than your project. You can build it custom to match your specific furniture layout, paint color, etc, and it will look awesome, but won't be ideal for other layouts. You can build it more general and do the typical semi-floods spaced so that beams meet at the floor in a slight venn-diagram. There's really no pre-baked formula; lighting design is a topic as complex as architectural and interior design temselves.

Answer (score 0):

DIALux evo is free and suggested by companies like Phillips. dialux.com

Phillips also provides a plug-in for their products that works in DIALux.